# MYSQL, Единый запрос и все, все, все

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, backend

Не сомневаюсь, что среди здешних пользователей есть профи SQL, поэтому хочу спросить следующее:
можно ли получить несколько **разных** SELECT одним **запросом**?

Есть следующий **SELECT**:

```
SELECT `ID`, `Teamname`, `User`, `Date_made` FROM `Team`
```

В **ответ** я получаю:

```
ID Teamname User Date_made
1  Sire     1    2020-02-20 18:28:46
2  Rulyatki 1    2020-03-03 16:07:38
```

И другой **SELECT**:

```
SELECT `ID`, `User`, `Book`, `Message`, `Date_pub` FROM `Comment`
```

**Ответ**:

```
ID User Book Message Date_pub
1  1    2    фывфыв  2020-02-22 15:57:42
```

В php это выглядит так:

```
[0] => [
   'ID' => '1',
   'Teamname' => 'Sire',
   'User' => '1',
   'Date_made' => '2020-02-20 18:28:46'
],
[1] => [
   'ID' => '2',
   'Teamname' => 'Rulyatki',
   'User' => '1',
   'Date_made' => '2020-03-03 16:07:38'
]
```

И

```
[0] => [
   'ID' => '1',
   'User' => 'Sire',
   'Book' => '1',
   'Message' => 'фывфыв',
   'Date_pub' => '2020-02-22 15:57:42'
]
```

Так что же я должен отправить на сервер, чтобы в ответ получить массив такого типа:

```
[0] => [    <----- Здесь ответ из первого SELECT
     [0] => [
       'ID' => '1',
       'Teamname' => 'Sire',
       'User' => '1',
       'Date_made' => '2020-02-20 18:28:46'
     ],
     [1] => [
       'ID' => '2',
       'Teamname' => 'Rulyatki',
       'User' => '1',
       'Date_made' => '2020-03-03 16:07:38'
     ]
],
[1] => [    <----- Здесь ответ из второго SELECT 
     [0] => [
       'ID' => '1',
       'User' => 'Sire',
       'Book' => '1',
       'Message' => 'фывфыв',
       'Date_pub' => '2020-02-22 15:57:42'
     ]
]
```

**Зачем мне это?** Я часто слышу от программистов, что нужно делать оптимизированные запросы и мне эта идея нравится, но на практике я столкнулся с проблемой. Все знают, что на **главной странице** сайта нужно выводить какую-нибудь актуальную информацию (последние комментарии, новости, и т.п.). Сейчас я делаю это так: **SELECT** для комментариев, **SELECT** для новостей, **SELECT** для рекомендация, **SELECT** для рекламы. В итоге выходит много **SELECT'ов**, что мне не нравится. Поэтому я и задался вопросом, можно ли это сделать одним разом **И** есть ли в этом **смысл**? Будет ли это работать **быстрее**?

Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос тупой, но я лично не понимаю, что делать.

Comment: "Слышу звон, да не знаю где он" это вот прям в тему. Оптимизацией нужно заниматься тогда, когда есть проблемы с производительностью. И только в том месте, где имеется проблема. Вы же пытаетесь делить шкуру не убитого медведя

Comment: Всегда нужно стремиться к лучше, так что не вижу ничего плохого в заранее оптимизированном коде.

Comment: Одним запросом полезно доставать связанную друг с другом информацию. А если информация никак не связана то смысла как то извращаться, что бы получить ее вместе нет

Comment: И для начала оптимизировать надо сами запросы. Что то я сомневаюсь, что у вас все запросы вот такие как вы показали, без единого условия. А в таблицах по 1-2 записи. Стоит убедиться что все запросы делают свою работу оптимально.

Comment: То что вы хотите сделать - это не лучше и не оптимизация. Если интересно что имеется ввиду, то наберите в поисковике "проблема выбора N + 1"

Comment: @Mike, сейчас не могу скинуть код. Условия там и правда есть, но не очень много, так как я добавляю только ограничения по кол-ву записей и сортирую по дате (ещё иногда получаю некоторые данные из других таблиц с помощью INNER JOIN).

Comment: Код ничего не даст. Для запросов надо смотреть планы выполнения с помощью explain и убеждаться, что они не устраивают переборов больших таблиц, а работают по индексам. Ну и что нет кучи обращений к одной и той же таблице

Comment: А что касается большого кол-ву обращений к множеству разных таблиц за не связанной информацией, то это оптимизируется (только при необходимости) различными технологиями кеширования готовых наборов данных в in memory хранилищах

Comment: @ArchDemon, почитал, но, видимо, моих знаний недостаточно, потому что даже с объяснениями я не понял, о чем идет речь.

Comment: И хотите оптимизировать код. Для начала нужно бы понять нуждается ли код в оптимизации.

Comment: Действительно, нет ничего плохого в заранее оптимизированном коде. Но не надо путать заранее оптимизированный код с заранее изуродованным кодом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот мой ответ адресован в первую очередь не автору вопроса, а отвечателям, завсегдатаям этого сайта.

Я уже много лет наблюдаю нездоровую тенденцию: ответить на поставленный вопрос любой ценой. Порвать заднюю часть тела в лоскуты, презреть здравый смысл и формальную логику, но в муках родить ответ - каким бы бессмысленным он не был.

Такое ощущение, что люди воспринимают вопрос не как практическую задачу, а как персональное тестовое задание адресованное лично им. Или, я не знаю -  как испытание, в котором за отрицательный ответ полагается смертная казнь. И с энтузиазмом принимаются строчить ответ.

В итоге вместо реальной помощи автор вопроса получает искусственного кадавра, уродливого монстра, который абсолютно нежизнеспособен, а - главное - решает **несуществующую задачу**.

У меня большая просьба к любителям отвечать: проводить минимальный аудит вопроса, оценивать его осмысленность. И не стесняться давать **отрицательный ответ**. Нет ничего плохого или постыдного в том, что на вопрос "как мне из 2х2 получить 5" ответить "никак". И рассказать что правильный ответ - 4.

Если человек боится выполнения 5 простых запросов на одной странице, то надо не кидаться удовлетворять его фантазии, продиктованные недостатком знаний и опыта. А  объяснить, что главное не количество, а качество запросов. И оптимизировать надо не количество, а качество. Сам по себе запрос в базу данных - очень простая операция. БД не кирпичи таскает чтобы ответить на запрос. Бояться запросов не надо. Без нужды плодить запросы, разумеется, не стоит, но и бояться запроса, который трубется для получения информации, и является оптимальным с точки зрения производительности, абсолютно не стоит.

> Я часто слышу от программистов, что нужно делать оптимизированные
>   запросы

Речь идет об оптимизации одного запроса, а не о запихивании 10 запросов в один. **Быстрее они от этого выполняться не станут.** Если среди этих десяти есть один медленный, то как бы ты их не рассаживал, в итоге страница всё равно будет грузиться медленно. И чтобы она грузилась быстро, надо оптимизировать медленный запрос, а не искать способ ускорить то, что и так работает быстро.

Answer (score -1):

Точно  так, как описано, сделать НЕВОЗМОЖНО. Причина - возвращаемый набор записей имеет строго определённую структуру, единую для всех записей набора.

В рамках заявленного сервера БД возможны минимум два решения, похожих на требуемое.

**Решение 1** - мультизапрос. Т.е. два запроса, разделённые штатным символом окончания текста запроса `;`, отправляются на сервер как один запрос, и в ответ возвращается два набора данных как единый массив/коллекция. Т.е. возвращаемые набор имеет два (или более) вложенных элемента, каждый из которых является самостоятельным набором данных, со своей структурой.

Формализованный пример:

```
result=connection.query("select id,val from t1; select id,txt,cnt from t2;")
```

Результат будет достаточно близок к структуре, показанной в вопросе.

**Решение 2** - синхронизация ("выравнивание") структур выходных данных и использование UNION ALL. Недостающие поля вводятся дополнительно в структуру отдельных запросов с соблюдением типа данных, и им присваивается некое константное значение (обычно NULL, но возможны также ноль, пустая строка или, скажем, литерал `'EMPTY'`). Обычно также вводится дополнительное поле, значение которого позволяет установить, к какому из объединённых наборов относится каждая конкретная запись, если это нельзя выяснить анализом значений полей, объявленных в исходных данных как NOT NULL или имеющих фиксированный непересекающийся набор значений.

Формализованный пример:

```
result=connection.query("select id, val , CAST(null AS CHAR) as txt, 0 as cnt from t1
                         union all
                         select id, null, txt                      , cnt      from t2;")
```

либо

```
result=connection.query("select '1' as setnum, id, val , CAST(null AS CHAR) as txt, 0 as cnt from t1
                         union all
                         select '2'          , id, null, txt                      , cnt      from t2;")
```